# Как узнать индекс первого символа второго элемента списка,если я не знаю его значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list, index

Hужно узнать индекс элемента списка, но я не знаю заранее что в списке, т.к юзер вводит данные, я знаю что первый символ первого элемента это `list[0]`. Kак мне узнать первый символ второго элемента не зная его длину?

Comment: Эмм... Стоит показать код ввода и пример ввода юзера.

Comment: ввод просто words = input("Введите предложение: ")
ввод юзера например "как дела?".нужно узнать индекс буквы "д"

Comment: Проверяй длины элементов. Сперва проверяешь саму последовательность, что она содержит хотя бы 2 элемента. Затем проверяешь длину второго лемента, что это не пустая строка. Ну а само обращение к первому символу второго элемента, это `list[1][0]`

Comment: words = input("Введите предложение: ") это не list , а string

Comment: а ну да,я ещё писал lst = words.split()

Comment: Найти индекс символа "пробел" и прибавить 1 ))

Comment: ' ' is not in list

Comment: @Daddy Эээ, так если у вас уже список, то не понимаю в чём проблема, это всегда будет именно 1-й символ 2-го элемента в списке и не важно какая там длина у чего )  Я думал нужен индекс в исходной строке.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы разделить входную строку на слова - элементы списка, можно использовать split

```
words = input("Введите предложение: ").split()
if len(words) > 1:
     d = words[1][0]
```

Comment: разве не [0][1] ?

Comment: @Интик Нет, ведь второй элемент, первый символ